# POST Method Anti-CSRF Help With Burp Suite

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, csrf, burp-suite

I am testing a web application and encountering anti-CSRF tokens within forms which is hampering fuzzing attempts using Burp Suite intruder. An anti-CSRF token appears as *csrf-token* within a HTML meta field. 
On submission of a form, the same token is URI encoded and sent as an *authenticity-token* parameter within the POST request body.

The application terminates the user session if the token is invalid, which is the case when running Intruder as the token is single use as expected (not for the life of the user session).

Although it seems straightforward, I've not been able to set with the guides below:
https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2906338-using-burp-s-session-handling-rules-with-anti-csrf-tokens
https://plusplussecurity.com/2016/11/14/csrf-tokens-using-macros-in-burp-suite-iii/

Selecting the request and the appropriate token does not seem to do much but testing the macro results in a new response with a fresh *csrf-token*.
Particularly, *authenticity-token* is not updated between each request and there is no evidence of the session handling rules working.

I would appreciate a good guide or assistance on this, as I'm not sure what I am missing at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the route I took eventually, thanks to the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWLMmkv3z38:

1. Identify the anti-CSRF token (e.g. hidden *csrf_token* field within
   the form)
2. Go to Project options > Sessions > Add to record a new macro.
3. In Macro Recorder, select the HTTP request from the proxy history
   and click "OK".
4. Select the Macro Item and hit configure item.
5. In the bottom right, *Add Custom Parameter*, highlighting the string
   that will be extracted for use as the anti-CSRF token. The '*Define
   start and end*' fields should be updated with the appropriate
   search terms. Populate the Parameter name field, with the description like
   *csrf-token*.
6. Add session handling rule.
7. Add a rule action (*Run a macro*) from the dropdown list.
8. Select *Update current request with parameters matched from final macro response*.
   Select *update only the following parameters* and enter the name of the parameter e.g. *authentication_token*.
9. Finally, click the Scope tab within the *Session handling rule editor* and    configure scope to the Burp Tools, Parameters and scope URLs desired.

I spent more time than I wanted on this issue so I hope this helps someone save some pain; if it's not clear let me know and I'll try to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the solution. Sometimes ago I wanted to automate a workflow where we would provide a list of username and passwords, and after authentication is successful, the user needed to submit a form. Eventually I gave up on Burp because I couldn't automate the workflow. Such things are not obvious with Burp the first time around but your solution will definitely help in some situations.

Comment: Thanks @void_in, what did you use instead of Burp?

Comment: We used Apache jmeter record session and then replay the whole session.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on the right lines. There isn't a more detailed tutorial than the one you linked.

To help you diagnose what's going wrong, open Sessions Tracer. Also, send a request to Repeater that has an authenticity token. What you want to see is that when you press Go in Repeater, the session handling rule activates, runs a macro to fetch a fresh token, and updates the request in Repeater. Knowing exactly which part of this isn't working should help you fix it.

Because the token is in a meta tag you will need to use a custom parameter location. In Macro Editor, click Configure Item, then add a Custom parameter location.

Alternatively, use Burp 2 which should handle this automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you elaborate on how Burp 2 handles this case automatically? I have tried the burpsuite_pro_v2.0.09beta.jar package, there is no indication that it is handling these tokens automatically.

Comment: @user1330734 - If you do a crawl & audit in Burp 2, the crawler understands state and should realize that it only gets to the forms success state via a fresh CSRF token. If this isn't working, we'd be keen to work with you to debug that. Please email what information you have to support@portswigger.net